# Python CLI mocking issues with dynamic input

Tags: python, testing, mocking, command-line-interface

I am working on a python CLI and have run into an issue when trying to test multiple mock side effects.  I have searched google, stackexchange, etc. but can not seem to use any of that information to get my code operating as expected and could really use an additional set of eyes.

Technologies being used:

- python 3.9.5
- Typer
- simple-term-menu
- pytest
- pytest-mock

The operational code executes as expected however the test scenarios do not.  Below is some pseudo code:
src/endpoints/cli.py

```
@cli.command()
def ls(
    env: Optional[str] = typer.Option(None, '--env', prompt=False),
    tool: Optional[str] = typer.Option(None, '--tool', prompt=False)

    results = get_results(env, tool)
    typer.echo(f"{str(results).rstrip()}")
    return str(results).rstrip()

def get_results(env, tool):
    if env is None:
        typer.echo("Please select an environment")
        env_select_menu = TerminalMenu(
            list_envs()
        )
        env_entry_index = env_select_menu.show()
        env = env_select_menu.chosen.menu_entry
        logging.debug(f"printing env: {env}")
        typer.echo(f"> {env}")
    if tool is None:
        typer.echo("Please select a tool")
        tool_select_menu = TerminalMenu(
            list_tools()
        )
        tool_entry_index = tool_select_menu.show()
        tool = tool_select_menu.chosen.menu_entry
        logging.debug(f"printing tool: {tool}")
        typer.echo(f"> {tool}")
```

test_cli.py

```
from typer.testing import CliRunner
from src.endpoints.cli import cli
import pytest
import logging

@pytest.mark.parameterize(
    "params,response",
    [
        (None, "Please select a domain")
    ]
)
def test_results(mocker, params, response, tool_results):
    if params:
        pass
    else:
        mock_terminal = mocker.patch("src.endpoints.cli.TerminalMenu")
        mock_terminal().chosen_menu_entry = 'test'

        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(cli, ['ls'])
        logging.debug(mock_terminal.mock_calls)
   
        assert "Please select an environment" in result.output
        assert "Please select a tool" in result.output
```

Resulting output:

```
DEBUG: root: printing env: test
DEBUG: root: env is test
> test
Please select a tool

DEBUG: root:[call(), call(['test']), call().__str__(), call().show()]
```

Expectant output:
Same as above but that the second time the TerminalMenu().chosen_menu_entry is called that it would respond again with 'test'.  Ideally I want to use a side_effect to return different results.  I have tried different variations of `mock_terminal().chosen_menu_entry.side_effect = ['test', 'test-tool']` but figured that I should address the issue of the mock response not returning the same value before trying different values using side_effect.  Does anyone see what I am doing wrong and why the return_value is not being used for the second call of TerminalMenu?  The test passes but looks to effectively not do anything with the tool_select_menu (which was the second calling of TerminalMenu).

Thank you in advance with any insight you may have.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.  I was able to use a combination of side_effect and PropertyMock to resolve the testing issues.